# Where to put the code in Electron Apps to make JavaScript work?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to get JavaScript I have written into my electron app. At the moment I am struggling to get anything to work.

I want the button to just change the page to show the date.

This is in the HTML.

```
<button onclick="myne()">PRESS ME</button>
```

And this is in the **index.js** file.

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const url = require('url')

function boot(){
win = new BrowserWindow()
win.setMenu(null);
win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: 'index.html',
    slashes: true
}))

function myne(){
document.write(date());
   }
}
```

I just can't get the JavaScript to run. I have tried using it as external file as well as trying to write the function outside of the boot function.

I have also tried the require JS things but I think I implemented it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the example below:

**main.js**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myne()">PRESS ME</button>
    <script>
      require('./renderer.js')
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**renderer.js**

```
window.myne = function() {
    document.write(new Date());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works I also added another function using the format of window first (That also worked). is that the way I would do it for everything?

Comment: This is the structure I see generally. You can look at this example with multiple windows: https://github.com/bunyaminsg/electron-fhir-client. Also, Electron Fiddle (https://github.com/electron/fiddle) does it this way.

Comment: Ok. What about adding external js files like jquery? there must be a way to link to the files without changing the format of the function in the files?

Comment: I usually use `const $ = require("jquery")` in the beginning of the renderer.js